# Predictive recursive descent parser for math expressions

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, math-expression-eval

I've been learning about language theory and parsing, and decided to write my first parser: a LL(1) recursive descent parser. But actually, it does a little more than just expressions; it can also parse variable definitions with the "define" keyword. It parses into an AST and then the other portion of the program evaluates the AST, but I'm not posting that half (right now at least).

tree.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

template <typename> struct t_unary_op;
template <typename> struct t_binary_op;
template <typename> struct t_nary_op;

template <typename NumType>
struct t_negate : public t_unary_op<NumType>
{
    template <typename... Args>
    t_negate(Args&&... args): t_unary_op<NumType>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_add : public t_binary_op<NumType>
{
    template <typename... Args>
    t_add(Args&&... args): t_binary_op<NumType>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_subtract : public t_binary_op<NumType>
{
    template <typename... Args>
    t_subtract(Args&&... args): t_binary_op<NumType>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_multiply : public t_binary_op<NumType>
{
    template <typename... Args>
    t_multiply(Args&&... args): t_binary_op<NumType>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_divide : public t_binary_op<NumType>
{
    template <typename... Args>
    t_divide(Args&&... args): t_binary_op<NumType>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_exponentiate : public t_binary_op<NumType>
{
    template <typename... Args>
    t_exponentiate(Args&&... args): t_binary_op<NumType>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_var_occurrance
{
    std::string name;

    t_var_occurrance(std::string _name): name(std::move(_name)) {}
};

template <typename>
struct t_func_invocation;

template <typename NumType>
struct t_arg_placeholder
{
    unsigned int index;

    t_arg_placeholder(unsigned int _index): index(_index) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
using t_expression = boost::variant<
                                    NumType,
                                    boost::recursive_wrapper<t_var_occurrance<NumType>>,
                                    boost::recursive_wrapper<t_func_invocation<NumType>>,
                                    boost::recursive_wrapper<t_arg_placeholder<NumType>>,
                                    boost::recursive_wrapper<t_negate<NumType>>,
                                    boost::recursive_wrapper<t_add<NumType>>,
                                    boost::recursive_wrapper<t_subtract<NumType>>,
                                    boost::recursive_wrapper<t_multiply<NumType>>,
                                    boost::recursive_wrapper<t_divide<NumType>>,
                                    boost::recursive_wrapper<t_exponentiate<NumType>>
                                    >;

template <typename NumType>
struct t_func_invocation
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<t_expression<NumType>> args;

    t_func_invocation(std::string _name, std::vector<t_expression<NumType>> _args): name(std::move(_name)), args(std::move(_args)) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_unary_op
{
    t_expression<NumType> op;

    template <typename Op>
    t_unary_op(Op&& _op): op(std::forward<Op>(_op)) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_binary_op
{
    t_expression<NumType> ops[2];

    template <typename Op1, typename Op2>
    t_binary_op(Op1&& op1, Op2&& op2): ops{std::forward<Op1>(op1), std::forward<Op2>(op2)} {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_nary_op
{
    std::vector<t_expression<NumType>> ops;

    template <typename... Ops>
    t_nary_op(Ops&&... _ops): ops{std::forward<Ops>(_ops)...} {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_var_definition
{
    std::string name;
    t_expression<NumType> val;

    t_var_definition(std::string _name, t_expression<NumType> _val): name(std::move(_name)), val(std::move(_val)) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
struct t_func_definition
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int arity;
    t_expression<NumType> val;

    t_func_definition(std::string _name, unsigned int _arity, t_expression<NumType> _val): name(std::move(_name)), arity(_arity), val(std::move(_val)) {}
};

template <typename NumType>
using t_statement = boost::variant<
                                   t_expression<NumType>,
                                   t_var_definition<NumType>,
                                   t_func_definition<NumType>
                                   >;
```

and lexer.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <exception>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class lex_error : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept
    {
        return "Unexpected character in input to lexer";
    }
};

enum class token_tag
{
    Invalid,
    Number,
    Character,
    Identifier,
    EOI
};

struct token
{
    token_tag type;
    boost::variant<boost::blank, double, char, std::string> value;

    token(): type(token_tag::Invalid), value() {}
    token(token_tag _type): type(_type), value() {}
    template <typename ValueType>
    token(token_tag _type, ValueType&& _value): type(_type), value(std::forward<ValueType>(_value)) {}
};

template <typename Iterator>
void skip_spaces(Iterator& first, Iterator last)
{
    while(first != last && isspace(*first)) ++first;
}

template <typename Iterator>
token get_token(Iterator& first, Iterator last)
{
    using namespace std;

    skip_spaces(first, last);
    if(first == last) return token(token_tag::EOI);

    string temp;
    bool decimal = false;

    switch(*first)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '^':
    case '(':
    case ')':
    case '=':
        goto accept_operator;

    case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f': case 'g': case 'h': case 'i': case 'j': case 'k': case 'l': case 'm':
    case 'n': case 'o': case 'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's': case 't': case 'u': case 'v': case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z':
        goto id;

    case '.':
        decimal = true;
        // Intentional fall-through
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
        goto number;

    default:
        throw lex_error();
    }

    accept_operator:
        return token(token_tag::Character, *first++);

    id:
        do
        {
            temp.push_back(*first++);
        } while(first != last && islower(*first));
        goto accept_id;

    accept_id:
        return token(token_tag::Identifier, std::move(temp));

    number:
        temp.push_back(*first++);
        if(first != last)
        {
            if(isdigit(*first))
                goto number;
            else if(*first == '.')
            {
                if(decimal == false)
                {
                    decimal = true;
                    goto number;
                }
                else
                    throw lex_error();
            }
        }
        goto accept_number;


    accept_number:
        if(decimal && temp.size() == 1)
            throw lex_error();
        char *dummy;
        double val = strtod(temp.c_str(), &dummy);
        return token(token_tag::Number, val);
}
```

and parser.h:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <exception>
#include <cmath>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include "lexer.h"
#include "tree.h"

class parse_error : public std::exception
{
    std::string msg;

public:
    parse_error(std::string _msg): exception(), msg(_msg) {}

    const char* what() const noexcept
    {
        return msg.c_str();
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct parser_state
{
    Iterator head, last;
    token lookahead;

    void scan()
    {
        lookahead = get_token(head, last);
    }

    parser_state(Iterator _first, Iterator _last): head(_first), last(_last), lookahead(token_tag::Invalid)
    {
        scan();
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
parser_state<Iterator> initialize_parser(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    return parser_state<Iterator>(first, last);
}

parser_state<std::istreambuf_iterator<char>> initialize_parser(std::istream& is)
{
    return parser_state<std::istreambuf_iterator<char>>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}

template <typename Iterator>
void throw_parse_error(parser_state<Iterator>& s, std::string rule, std::string expected)
{
    using namespace std;

    ostringstream o;
    o << "In rule " << rule << ": expected " << expected << ", got ";

    if(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::EOI)
        o << "end-of-input.";
    else if(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::Character)
        o << '\'' << boost::get<char>(s.lookahead.value) << "'.";
    else if(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::Number)
        o << "number " << boost::get<double>(s.lookahead.value) << '.';
    else
        o << "invalid token.";

    throw parse_error(o.str());
}

template <typename Iterator>
void parse_expression(parser_state<Iterator>&, t_expression<double>&);

template <typename Iterator>
void parse_factor(parser_state<Iterator>&, t_expression<double>&);

template <typename Iterator>
void parse_parenthesized_expression(parser_state<Iterator>& s, t_expression<double>& t)
{
    if(s.lookahead.type != token_tag::Character || boost::get<char>(s.lookahead.value) != '(')
        throw_parse_error(s, "parenthesized-expression", "'('");

    s.scan();

    parse_expression(s, t);

    if(s.lookahead.type != token_tag::Character || boost::get<char>(s.lookahead.value) != ')')
        throw_parse_error(s, "parenthesized-expression", "')'");
}

template <typename Iterator>
void parse_atom(parser_state<Iterator>& s, t_expression<double>& t)
{
    using namespace std;

    char op;
    auto type = s.lookahead.type;

    if(type == token_tag::Number)
    {
        t = boost::get<double>(s.lookahead.value);
    }
    else if(type == token_tag::Identifier)
    {
        t = t_var_occurrance<double>(move(boost::get<string>(s.lookahead.value)));
    }
    else if(type == token_tag::Character)
    {
        parse_parenthesized_expression(s, t);
    }
    else
        throw_parse_error(s, "atom", "number, identifier, or '('");

    s.scan();

    if(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::Character)
    {
        op = boost::get<char>(s.lookahead.value);

        if(op == '^')
        {
            s.scan();

            t_expression<double> c;
            parse_factor(s, c);
            t = t_exponentiate<double>(t, c);
        }
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void parse_factor(parser_state<Iterator>& s, t_expression<double>& t)
{
    if(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::Character)
    {
        char op = boost::get<char>(s.lookahead.value);

        if(op == '+')
        {
            s.scan();
            parse_factor(s, t);
        }
        else if(op == '-')
        {
            s.scan();

            t_expression<double> c;
            parse_factor(s, c);
            t = t_negate<double>(c);
        }
        else
            parse_atom(s, t);
    }
    else
        parse_atom(s, t);
}

template <typename Iterator>
void parse_term(parser_state<Iterator>& s, t_expression<double>& t)
{
    parse_factor(s, t);
    while(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::Character)
    {
        char op = boost::get<char>(s.lookahead.value);
        if(op != '*' && op != '/')
            break;

        s.scan();

        t_expression<double> c;
        parse_factor(s, c);
        if(op == '*')
            t = t_multiply<double>(t, c);
        else
            t = t_divide<double>(t, c);
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void parse_expression(parser_state<Iterator>& s, t_expression<double>& t)
{
    if(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::Character && boost::get<char>(s.lookahead.value) == ')')
        throw_parse_error(s, "expression", "number, identifier, '+', '-' or '('");

    parse_term(s, t);

    while(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::Character)
    {
        char op = boost::get<char>(s.lookahead.value);

        if(op == '+' || op == '-')
        {
            s.scan();

            t_expression<double> c;
            parse_term(s, c);
            if(op == '+')
                t = t_add<double>(t, c);
            else
                t = t_subtract<double>(t, c);
        }
        else break;
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void parse_definition(parser_state<Iterator>& s, t_statement<double>& t)
{
    using namespace std;

    string name = move(boost::get<string>(s.lookahead.value));

    s.scan();

    if(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::Character && boost::get<char>(s.lookahead.value) == '=')
    {
        s.scan();

        t_expression<double> e;
        parse_expression(s, e);
        t = t_var_definition<double>(move(name), std::move(e));
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void parse_root(parser_state<Iterator>& s, t_statement<double>& t)
{
    if(s.lookahead.type == token_tag::Identifier && boost::get<std::string>(s.lookahead.value) == "define")
    {
        s.scan();
        parse_definition(s, t);
    }
    else
    {
        t_expression<double> e;
        parse_expression(s, e);
        t = std::move(e);
    }

    if(s.lookahead.type != token_tag::EOI)
        throw_parse_error(s, "root", "end-of-input");
}
```

I will post all files on a separate website if anyone requests.

I'm mostly OK with the way my AST is set up, but I feel like the lexer is REALLY messy, and the parser is a little confusing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it intentional that you skip the `'k'` in `get_token()`?

Comment: @Aurelius Nope! TIL that I don't know the alphabet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've posted a lot of code, so this review focuses primarily on `lexer.h`, which you've indicated may have the most to improve.

## Code Style

### Use include guards

[Include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) ensure that you don't get symbol-redefinition errors when a header is included multiple times. You should wrap your headers with a unique macro definition:

```
#ifndef MY_PARSER_TREE
#define MY_PARSER_TREE
// header contents go here
#endif
```

### `#include` organization

It is a good idea to keep your standard library `#include` directives sorted alphabetically. This makes it easy to spot duplicates, or to add new dependencies in the right position.

### Iterator categories

If you have an interface which takes iterators, you should at least specify the category of iterator which your algorithm requires. For instance, if `skip_spaces()` requires input iterators, you should name the iterator type as such:

```
template <typename InputIterator> // or InputIt for short
```

This is the convention followed by the standard library. If you want more safety than mere convention, there are metaprogramming solutions in the standard library (like `std::enable_if`).

## Logic

### Don't use `goto`

While there may be (very, *very* rare) legitimate uses of `goto`, it should almost [never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451/is-it-ever-advantageous-to-use-goto-in-a-language-that-supports-loops-and-func/24476#24476). It makes your program hard to reason about. If you're tempted to use it, take a step back and re-think your design. This is related to my next point:

### Reconsider use of `switch`

I hardly ever use `switch` statements, usually because there is a better abstraction that serves the same purpose. Your switch statement appears to be handling three distinct cases: digit, lower-case letter, and operator. As a first step, I would create functions that encapsulate the identification and handling of each case:

```
const auto character = *first;
if (is_operator(character))
{
    // handle it...
}
else if (islower(character))
{
    // handle it...
}
else // etc.
```

#### Predicate functions

Creating functions to identify a character is clearer and less error-prone. It's easy to forget to type a letter when you create a `case` for each lower-case letter. There are two standard-library functions `islower()` and `isdigit()` which cover most of the ground in your `switch`.

Your operators can be represented as a `std::set`, and then testing is straightforward:

```
bool is_operator(char c)
{
    const std::set<char> operators = {'+', '-', '*', '/', '^', '(', ')', '='};
    return operators.find(c) != operators.end();
}
```

If you want to be more flexible, you could read these operator symbols from a file, but the principle is the same.

### Reinventing the wheel

Some of your code replicates functionality that already exists in the standard library. `skip_spaces` can be replaced by `find_if_not`:

```
first = std::find_if_not(first, last, isspace);
```

And your construction of `temp` under the `id` label:

```
string temp; // earlier
do
{
    temp.push_back(*first++);
} while(first != last && islower(*first));
```

can similarly be clarified using a few algorithms and the `string` constructor taking iterators:

```
const auto nonLowercase = std::find_if_not(first, last, islower); // much clearer
const string temp{first, nonLowercase};
first = nonLowercase;
```

### Unnecessary constructor

The single-argument `token` constructor is only called once, with an `Invalid` tag. This behavior is identical to the default constructor, so you could remove the constructor and change the single usage to call the default constructor. This will tighten up the interface for `token`. It doesn't make sense to create a token with no data that isn't `Invalid`, right?

Comment: Although I agree with the avoidance of `goto` in the general case, I am using it here to represent an actual finite state machine. I know I could refactor it out into a loop and a state variable, but why do that when labels and `goto`s pretty much explicitly present my purpose of changing "state"? Also, the switch statement is "faster" in a sense; a compiler can [optimize it to a jump table](http://741mhz.com/switch/), which is ideal in the case of a lexer. Ideally, a lexer will look at each input character exactly once to make decisions (not counting operations after a decision is made).

Comment: But yeah, good points, thank you. +1. BTW I actually already had the header guards, I just accidentally didn't copy them over :)

Comment: @mebob I grant there may be performance benefits to your implementation. My comments were directed at correctness and maintainability. I still think that exit from the `switch` could be better handled than using `goto`, even if you don't want to test using a series of `if` statements. The only case where you actually jump back to a label is in `number:`. The rest just advance to the next "state". I think it would be clearer to use a function. I'm glad you found my comments helpful!

Comment: I know this is an old answer but why not just use `first = nonLowercase` instead of `std::advance(first, std::distance(first, nonLowercase))` ?